# cannot use pyperclip module in python shell after successful download

Tags: python, module, pip

-> I have successfully installed the module pyperclip through the command prompt:

C:\Users\joao_>pip install pyperclip
Requirement already satisfied: pyperclip in c:\users\joao_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.8.0)

-> Unfortunately, when I try to use it in the interactive shell it gives me this error:

> > > import pyperclip
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >           import pyperclip
> > >       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip'

I fear that the installation was made in a different directory than the one that it was supposed to. The command prompt says it was installed in the Anaconda directory but I don't know how to change that. It is probably a simple mistake but I haven't been able to get around it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+module+installed+import+error

Comment: In short: `pip` installed the package into one Python and you're trying to import it in another. Use one Python for installation and importing.